# How to remove Angular Universal on angular project

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I enabled angular universal on my project . I would like to remove it completely now. I tried to remove the following files

```
/server.ts
/webpack.server.config.js
/src/tsconfig.server.json
/src/main.server.ts
/src/app/app.server.module.ts
and remove server section in angular.json
```

but, It has not removed completely.

Is there any command to remove it completely?

Comment: Did you review the angular.json file configurations? I think you'll need to remove configurations from there too.

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me (from `"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^13.1.0",`):

1. Use `npm` to remove these dependences:

```
npm uninstall @nguniversal/express-engine
npm uninstall @nguniversal/builders
npm uninstall express
npm uninstall @types/express
```

2. Remove from your solution these files:

```
./server.ts    
./tsconfig.server.json    
./src/main.server.ts
./src/app/app.server.module.ts
// Delete `*webpack.server` config file if exists!
```

3. Delete not necessary code of your configuration files:

- From *package.json*, delete ssr-scripts:

```
 "dev:ssr": "ng run info-rincon:serve-ssr",
 "serve:ssr": "node dist/functions/server/main.js",
 "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run info-rincon:server:production",
 "prerender": "ng run info-rincon:prerender",
```

- From *angular.json*, delete "server" or "prerender" sections:

[image: Remove server, server-ssr and prerender sections]

- From *app.module.ts*, delete *withServerTransition*:

[image: Remove withServerTransition area]

```
* From _app-routing.module.ts_, this is not needed:
```

[image]

4. If you have been using firebase, @angular/fire, Google Cloud Functions or something like that... perhaps you also need to search and delete more code:

[image: Remove functions configuration]

Comment: If you are using the Visual Studio IDE, you will want to remove the dist-server part from the publish paths in the project file as well :
<DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />

Answer (score -2):

Based on Angular documentation on the following link https://angular.io/guide/universal

looking up at the second section of the page (Universal tutorial) it will show you the files that are created using angular universal which are :-

```
src/index.html
src/main.ts    
src/main.server.ts    
src/style.css    
app/... app.server.module.ts    
server.ts    
tsconfig.json    
tsconfig.app.json    
tsconfig.server.json    
tsconfig.spec.json    
package.json    
webpack.server.config.js
```

i would delete these files completely and/or delete the sections in these files that are angular-universal related

Comment: some files like tsconfig.json, package.json are being modified not deleted!

Comment: you would delete src/main.ts??

Comment: Look out! Some of those files (tsconfig.json, tsconfig.app.json or package.json) are just modified, not created, as they are essential for the angular app