# Angular 17 - ng build - dist folder generation

Tags: angular, deployment, build, angular-components, angular17

I have developed a project using the Angular 17 tool. This was creating the two sets of folders for the server and browser during the creation(build) of the dist folder. That was not the case with the previous edition.

In order to use this app as a component in another app, I must obtain the bundle script file. How can I adjust the settings to create the same dist folder as the prior version, then?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your application seems to be configured as server-side rendering.
In this case, the "ng build" command produces two folders (browser-server)

You can create a new clientside application and import your files to clear project or > [How to remove Angular Universal on angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508632/how-to-remove-angular-universal-on-angular-project)